# Cannot scrape from Johns Hopkins covid-19 site with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from Johns Hopkins' Covid-19 site, and am trying the below code:

```
import scrapy
from datetime import date

class jhSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jh'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        
        urls = ['http://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv/']

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        today = today[6:11]+today[3:5]+today[0:2]
        filename = 'jhdata_covid_{}.html'.format(today)

        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

but the html file does not even get created. However, when I replace the URL with "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/", everything works fine.

Comment: Could you show your full `scrapy crawl jh` output?

Comment: Is there a reason why you try scraping instead of just downloading the raw data?

Answer (score 1):

I think that using scrapy is an overkill in this case unless you have a very good reason not to click on `raw` github button and right click > save as ...

For reading a table you might use `pandas` `read_html()` method like the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_html('https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv/')
```

*OUT:*

```
[     Unnamed: 0 Province/State      Country/Region  ...  8/11/20  8/12/20  8/13/20
0           NaN            NaN         Afghanistan  ...     1344     1354     1363
1           NaN            NaN             Albania  ...      205      208      213
2           NaN            NaN             Algeria  ...     1322     1333     1341
3           NaN            NaN             Andorra  ...       52       53       53
4           NaN            NaN              Angola  ...       80       80       80
..          ...            ...                 ...  ...      ...      ...      ...
261         NaN            NaN  West Bank and Gaza  ...      104      105      106
262         NaN            NaN      Western Sahara  ...        1        1        1
263         NaN            NaN               Yemen  ...      523      528      528
264         NaN            NaN              Zambia  ...      241      246      246
265         NaN            NaN            Zimbabwe  ...      104      122      128
```

[266 rows x 210 columns]]

If you had another thing in mind and you need scrapy to work on this very specific example:

You either:

- set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` in `settings.py` to False:

  ```
    ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
  ```

or

- call the spider like the following:

  ```
    scrapy crawl jh -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
  ```

why? because after running the spider I got an indication in scrapy log that you did not include in your post that after being redirected to github's [robots.txt](https://github.com/robots.txt) your request was declined

```
20-08-15 08:54:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://github.com/robots.txt> from <GET http://github.com/robots.txt>
2020-08-15 08:54:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://github.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-08-15 08:54:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET http://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv/>
```